# Twilio SDK java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.webrtc.EncodedImage"

Tags: java, android, twilio

I'm having issues with the twilio sdk in an existing android app. I'm trying to add it but at runtime I get this error:

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.webrtc.EncodedImage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/io.syftr.android.debug-Vm1y_uqJyGerI0IkYLNUzg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.syftr.android.debug-Vm1y_uqJyGerI0IkYLNUzg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/io.syftr.android.debug-Vm1y_uqJyGerI0IkYLNUzg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
> ```
>
> 2019-01-30 13:33:48.294 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.294 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.294 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.294 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1014)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.SystemLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(SystemLibraryLoader.java:24)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibraryInternal(ReLinkerInstance.java:163)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibrary(ReLinkerInstance.java:136)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:70)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:51)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.twilio.video.MediaFactory.instance(MediaFactory.java:44)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.twilio.video.LocalAudioTrack.create(LocalAudioTrack.java:95)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.twilio.video.LocalAudioTrack.create(LocalAudioTrack.java:42)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at io.syftr.android.components.bidchat_webrtc.video_call.VideoCallActivity.connectToRoom(VideoCallActivity.java:250)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at io.syftr.android.components.bidchat_webrtc.video_call.VideoCallActivity.onCreate(VideoCallActivity.java:202)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.295 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   2019-01-30 13:33:48.296 14906-14906/io.syftr.android.debug W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

And this is the graddle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'





repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 64 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

def gitSha() {
    def p = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir)
    p.waitFor()
    if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException(p.errorStream.text)
    }

    return p.text.trim()
}

def gitTimestamp() {
    def p = 'git log -n 1 --format=%at'.execute([], rootDir)
    p.waitFor()
    if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException(p.errorStream.text)
    }

    return p.text.trim()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    signingConfigs {
        //
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.syftr.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true

        //suppress Gradle 3.0.0 "references to other resources are not supported" errors
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true

        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        signingConfig signingConfigs.syftr

        buildConfigField 'String', 'GIT_SHA', "\"${gitSha()}\""
        buildConfigField 'long', 'GIT_TIMESTAMP', "${gitTimestamp()}L"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix 'debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.syftr

            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            applicationIdSuffix 'debug'
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.syftr
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        alpha {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix 'debug'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.syftr
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    // Specifies flavor dimensions for Gradle Plugin 3.0.0.
    flavorDimensions "standard"

    productFlavors {
        syftr {
            applicationId "io.syftr.android"
            dimension "standard"

        }
        l4l {
            applicationId "io.syftr.android"
            dimension "standard"
        }
        dskreat {
            applicationId "io.syftr.android"
            dimension "standard"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
    daggerVersion = '2.9'
    okhttp3Version = '3.12.1'
    retrofit2Version = '2.5.0'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.5.1'
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:$supportLibVersion"

    //    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2Version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2Version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3Version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnifeVersion"

    //Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.4'
    implementation 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    implementation 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.1.0'

    //compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.26.0'

    //    compile ('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'){
//        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'

//    }
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.26.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:0.7.9'

//    implementation 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar'
implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.1'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
implementation project(':adcolony-sdk-3.1.2')
implementation(name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar')

//added by jayesh 3518, dependency for circular image view
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

//added by jayesh 7518, firestore dependency
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'

// added by mukesh for WebRTC impl
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

// crop image approach changed on 23/08/18
implementation 'com.naver.android.helloyako:imagecropview:1.2.0'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

//added by jayesh 29818, library to display the gif
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:25.4.0'

// The Video library resides on jcenter

//implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:3.2.2'
// The Video library resides on jcenter
implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:2.2.1'

//    implementation(name: 'twilio-video-android-3.2.2', ext: 'aar')

//    implementation group: 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker', name: 'relinker', 

version: '1.2.2'
}

//fileTree(dir: 'libs-aar', include: '*.aar').each { File file -> dependencies.add("compile", [name: file.name.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, ''), ext: 'aar']) }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the proguard file here:

```
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
-keep class com.twilio.video.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Any ideas why this is happening and what I could do about it?

Comment: are you sure the proguard file is being read?

Comment: How can I be sure?

Comment: mm, add something obvious to it, to keep something that would normally be removed (like a class with no references in a new package), then inspect (unzip) the built apk to see if the class exists inside.

Comment: @Blundell I've disabled proguard just to see what happens and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've also checked the files from the apk. The classes mentioned to be missing are there in the apk.

Comment: ah ok, so its not a proguard issue. Could be a multi-dex issue? Have you tried enabling that?

Comment: That's enabled as well.

Comment: sorry can't help any further than that, I think you need to start deleting things until you have the smallest possible app that reproduces the issue